# calculate surface area of a spherical ball's portion

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, noneuclidean-geometry

Imagine a spherical ball with radius r that equally coated into two hemisphere P(grey) and S(white) is thrown at the pool. Consider the ball can float (up-down) and rotate. There is an interface separate two different fluid A(air) and B(water). Assume that the interface is flat. α defines the position of the ball and β defines the orientation of the ball. So α larger means ball is more in zone A and vice versa. Range of β and α is $[0,360^0]$ and $[0,180^0]$. The Schematic representation of this is below.
[image]

To calculate the surface area of P(grey) coated portion of the ball into A(air) is given by following equation, 
$\mathrm{Area}_{P@A}= 
r^2\int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta}^\alpha 
\int_{\phi=\arcsin(1/(\tan\theta \tan \beta))}
^{\pi -\arcsin(1/(\tan\theta \tan \beta)} \sin\theta\; d\theta d\phi.$

After solving this equation, we can get the following solution. 
$\textrm{Area}_{P@A}=
2 r^2 \left\{
\cos (\alpha) \sin ^{-1}(\cot (\alpha) \cot (\beta))
-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos (\beta)}{\sqrt{\sin ^2(\beta)-\cos ^2(\alpha)}}\right)\right\}+\pi  r^2 (1-\cos (\alpha)).$

Note that the solution is defined as a function of α and β. If we change the value of α and β, the area of P coated portion into A(air) will change eventually. Thus we can calculate the area for all valid condition of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Now consider a different situation where P and S are not equally coated rather S>P. To show that I have introduced another angle γ also $r1$ the radius of the base of the cap.
[image]

Now how can i write $z$ as an increased angle? what will be the limits of integration for a spherical cap? Is there any particular analytical solution exists to calculate the area P(grey) into A(air) as a function of $α,γ,β$?